# Hide UINavigationController Top bar in storyBoard view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Im trying to hide the navigation controller top bar from my storyboard view, because i'm actually hiding it programmatically and when Iloit's getting reescaled in execution time

Here is an image so you can understand it in a better way:
[image]

that top bar it's not appearing in my app and I would like to hide it in the storyboard too.
Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215533/storyboard-hiding-top-bar-of-navigation-controller-programmatically

Comment: Nope, he's hiding it programmatically already. He wants to hide it in the storyboard.

Comment: That's it, I'm hidding it programatically, but i don't want to see it in the storyboard view (i have search long for this so I don't think there is any duplicate ) thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the Navigation Controller, and go to the settings in the right bar :

[image]

In the "Navigation Controler" section, uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar", and you're good to go !

Here is what you'll get :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can turn it off using below Code i hope this will work for you !

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```