# How to add bar tab controller to viewContoller without adding a tab

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do i add a tab bar controller to a view Controller without adding it to the navigation bar?

I would like a Page that will flip though information but still have the navigation bar at the bottom

so i have a navigation controller hooked up to five viewControllers with a swipe gesture but after you swipe from the first page i lose the bar tab. I would like to add it to the others to navigate back faster

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215533/storyboard-hiding-top-bar-of-navigation-controller-programmatically

Comment: I figured this out when you show to a new View Contoller attach a segue from the back button to a this function in your new Viewcontoller        @IBAction func Dismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }