# Is there a way to move a SwiftUI view contained within a UIHostingController into the NavBar Space

Tags: swift, storyboard, swiftui

My current implementation appends the UIHostingController below the NavBar. But I want the UIhostingController to begin at the end of the status bar (the gray area below the notch). Here is the code and resulting image:

```
    self.reviewHomePage = ReviewHomePage(reviewDict: reviewDict)
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: self.reviewHomePage)
    self.addChild(hostingController)
    hostingController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

[image: Resulting View of Code Above]

I have tried to hide the NavBar using the various techniques discussed here: [Storyboard - Hiding top bar of navigation controller programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215533/storyboard-hiding-top-bar-of-navigation-controller-programmatically). But after hiding the NavBar, the space the NavBar occupies is still reserved for the NavBar (the background color is just changed to gray). I have tried to adjust the frame to start within the navBar space with the following code:

```
let navHeight = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.minY
let topFullView = ((self.navigationController?.view.frame.minY)!) + (navHeight) 
let reviewFrame = CGRect(x: (self.navigationController?.view.frame.minX)!,
                     y: (topFullView),
                     width: self.navigationController!.view.frame.width,
                     height: self.navigationController!.view.frame.height - topFullView)
```

But the UIHostingController is moved up behind the NavBar as shown in the image below. 
[image: Resulting View of Adjusted Frame]

Is it possible to completely remove the NavBar or append the view on top of the NavBar while maintaining the TabBar at the bottom of the screen? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this? I'm facing the same issue.